# Selecting lines in PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, string

I have code:

```
$dir=(new-object Net.WebClient).DownloadString("http://www.nbp.pl/kursy/xml/dir.txt")
$dir | foreach {
    if ($_.startswith("a"))
    {
        write-host $_
    }
}
```

and I need to select only lines that begin with `a` character. This script is not working, it does not print anything. What should I change in this script to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$dir` is a single string with newline characters inside, thus `foreach` runs only once in your example (you will print the whole string if you change the condition to `if ($_.startswith("c"))`.

You need to split the `$dir` variable, for example with:

```
$dir=(new-object Net.WebClient).DownloadString("http://www.nbp.pl/kursy/xml/dir.txt")
foreach ($singleEntry in $dir -split '\r\n') {
    if ($singleEntry.startswith("a"))
    {
        write-host $singleEntry
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! Can I remove all not `a` beginning lines from `$dir`?

Comment: Not sure what the new question is about... Of course you can.